Flutter: Set max Height for "DropDownMultiSelect"
Using package:multiselect/multiselect.dart : multiselect
The menu is too big.
I want to set MaxHeight for my Menu without migrating to new widgets.Couldnt find any way to do it.
Example code:
                    DropDownMultiSelect<Role>(
                              options: List.from(state.rolesList ?? []),
                              selectedValues: List.from(state.selectedRoles),
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: AppColors.gray900Color,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (value) {

                              },
                              menuItembuilder: (option) {
                                return ....
                              },
                              childBuilder: (selectedValues) {
                                return ....
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                              decoration: StylesHelper.adminInputDecoration,
                              whenEmpty: 'selectRole'.tr(),
                            ),

Thanks for everyone who tries to help .

can you wrap it with a SizedBox and provide some hight?

Only changes the width of the button not the whole menu.
You can test it with a random minmal app.
